# Как парсить в node.js?

Tags: node.js, парсер

Появилась проблема с парсингом в node.js. Я беру данные с сайта с помощью `superagent`:

```
{"users":[{"user_id":2714828,"username":"DevilPanda","user_message_count":25,"user_register_date":1571566134,"user_like_count":13,"user_title":"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447\u043e\u043a","user_is_valid":true,"user_is_verified":true,"user_is_followed":false,"user_last_seen_date":1617543573,"links":{"permalink":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/members\/2714828\/","detail":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/","avatar":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/data\/avatars\/m\/2714\/2714828.jpg?1571566134","avatar_big":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/data\/avatars\/l\/2714\/2714828.jpg?1571566134","avatar_small":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/data\/avatars\/s\/2714\/2714828.jpg?1571566134","followers":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/followers","followings":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/followings","ignore":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/ignore","timeline":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/timeline"},"permissions":{"edit":false,"follow":false,"ignore":false,"profile_post":false},"user_is_ignored":false,"user_is_visitor":false}]}
```

Из полученных данных я пытаюсь получить `username`. Пытался по разному:

`body.users[1]`

`body.users[username]`

`body.users['username']`

`body.users.username`

Но везде получаю `undefined`. Как мне нужно парсить?

Вот код:

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
const { body } = await superagent
  .get("https://lolz.guru/api/index.php?users/find&username=" + args);
  console.log(body.users)
  console.log(body.users.username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там возвращается результат в виде JSON. Его и нужно парсить:

```js
let body = '{"users":[{"user_id":2714828,"username":"DevilPanda","user_message_count":25,"user_register_date":1571566134,"user_like_count":13,"user_title":"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447\u043e\u043a","user_is_valid":true,"user_is_verified":true,"user_is_followed":false,"user_last_seen_date":1617543573,"links":{"permalink":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/members\/2714828\/","detail":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/","avatar":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/data\/avatars\/m\/2714\/2714828.jpg?1571566134","avatar_big":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/data\/avatars\/l\/2714\/2714828.jpg?1571566134","avatar_small":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/data\/avatars\/s\/2714\/2714828.jpg?1571566134","followers":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/followers","followings":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/followings","ignore":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/ignore","timeline":"https:\/\/lolz.guru\/api\/index.php?users\/2714828\/timeline"},"permissions":{"edit":false,"follow":false,"ignore":false,"profile_post":false},"user_is_ignored":false,"user_is_visitor":false}]}';

let parsed = JSON.parse(body);

console.log(parsed.users[0].username);
console.log(parsed.users);
```

P.S. Это безотносительно библиотеки superagent, возможно в ней есть уже готовый метод.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!